# Vuepress - How to add Custom html in head tag only on Particular Page?

Tags: vue.js, head, vuepress

I want to add Schema Tags and load my custom CSS in **head tag** on some particular pages not all, So is their any easy way to do that as I am not a coder, Can anyone help me regarding this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To Add custom style to the default installed vuepress I use the following code in `index.styl` under `.vuepress/styles/` to update `content__default` css class:

```
/**
 * Custom Styles here.
 *
 * ref：https://v1.vuepress.vuejs.org/config/#index-styl
 */

.home .hero img
  max-width 450px!important
.content__default
  background-color  #3df085
```

**Screen:**
[image]

About SEO tags I suggest [loris](https://lorisleiva.com/) [plugin](https://github.com/lorisleiva/vuepress-plugin-seo)

---

after reading your comment I see a [custom layout](https://v1.vuepress.vuejs.org/theme/default-theme-config.html#custom-layout-for-specific-pages) is the solution.

Add tags to head via `config.js`:

```
  head: [
    ['meta', { name: 'theme-color', content: '#3eaf7c' }],
    ['meta', { name: 'apple-mobile-web-app-capable', content: 'yes' }],
    ['meta', { name: 'apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style', content: 'black' }],
  
  ['meta', { 'property': 'og:type', 'content': 'article' }]
  ],
```

---

**Easy customization using default theme**:

1. Custom style for each page using [custom page class](https://v1.vuepress.vuejs.org/theme/default-theme-config.html#custom-page-class).
2. Add tags for each page using [yaml header](https://vuepress.vuejs.org/guide/frontmatter.html#meta).

Example for #1 & #2:

/blog/README.md

```
---
pageClass: blog-page
home: true
heroText: Hero Title
actionLink: /blog/
meta:
  - name: description
    content: blog page by abuabdellah
  - name: keywords
    content: super duper SEO
---

# Introduction

This is a test for a blog using v1 Vuepress
```

/guide/README.md

```
---
pageClass: guide-page
meta:
  - name: description
    content: guide page by abuabdellah
  - name: keywords
    content: super duper SEO
---

# Introduction

VuePress is composed of two parts
```

index.styl

```
.theme-container.blog-page
  background-color blue !important

.theme-container.guide-page
  background-color green !important
```

Comment: Hello Thanks for your answer but loris plugin doesn't have options that I need and also sorry I didn't mentioned I want to add html in head tag.

And I want to add style in a single page not in all I mentioned it.

Comment: I updated the answer after reading your comment.

Comment: Thanks but it's adding that meta tags I want some other things also to load in head and also it's loading in all pages and I need it in single page so that no conflicts are there between seo tags.

Comment: peace be upon those who follow guidance, I updated it with a new solution.